# C++ How to add and to an array without copying the data?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory

I have given a data buffer of type `uint8_t[n]`. Now I have to add to this array a *head* i.e. one value of `uint8_t` before. But I don't want to memcpy the data!

Given Array:

```
0x0800 - Start of data buffer
...
0x0900 - End of data buffer
```

New Array:

```
0x07ff - Head
0x0800 - Start of data buffer
...
0x0900 - End of data buffer
```

Is there any possibility to do that or is there a problem with memory allocation?

Comment: If you don't know exactly what is in front of the block of memory you have been given, inserting a value there is an awesomely bad idea.

Comment: If you can't control how much and where the memory for the buffer is allocated, then this is not possible without allocating new memory and copying everything over.

Answer (score 3):

If not moving memory around is what's important to you, then [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) can do that for you:

> `std::deque` (double-ended queue) is an indexed sequence container that allows fast insertion and deletion at both its beginning and its end. In addition, **insertion and deletion at either end of a deque never invalidates pointers or references to the rest of the elements**.
>
> As opposed to `std::vector`, the elements of a deque are not stored contiguously: typical implementations use a sequence of individually allocated fixed-size arrays, with additional bookkeeping, which means indexed access to `std::deque` must perform two pointer dereferences, compared to vector's indexed access which performs only one.
>
> The storage of a deque is automatically expanded and contracted as needed. **Expansion of a deque is cheaper than the expansion of a `std::vector` because it does not involve copying of the existing elements to a new memory location**. On the other hand, deques typically have large minimal memory cost; a deque holding just one element has to allocate its full internal array (e.g. 8 times the object size on 64-bit libstdc++; 16 times the object size or 4096 bytes, whichever is larger, on 64-bit libc++).

Comment: Great idea, but I don't think, based on comment in a now-deleted answer, OP has any control over how they get the data. They get an array of `uint8_t`. They'd have to copy that array into the `deque`.